# BASH - trap CTRL+C - Are you sure prompt doesn't always work

Tags: bash, ctrl, bash-trap

I've added the following to the top of my bash script:

```
quit() {

echo "Do you want to quit ? (y/n)"
  read n
  if [ "$n" = 'y' ]; then
    exit
  fi

}

trap quit INT
trap quit SIGINT
trap quit SIGTERM
```

The script asks the user a series of questions and then performs actions based on the results. Pressing <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> seems to work some of the time.

But other times I just get `Do you want to quit ? (y/n)` and the script locks up.  This may happen when in an IF statement or within WHILE / DONE.

But it seems to be if you time the <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> when an echo happens I can make the issue happen..  ie: <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> at the same time as the echo.

Is there a way to always trap <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> and prompt the user ? then let them decide if they want to quit or not ?

This code shows the issue happening..

```
quit() {

echo "Do you want to quit ? (y/n)"
  read n
  if [ "$n" = 'y' ]; then
    exit
  fi

}

trap quit INT
trap quit SIGINT
trap quit SIGTERM

for i in `seq 1 50`; do
    sleep 1
    echo -e "........"
    read -i "0000" -e site
done
```

Try to time the <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> just as the '........' and 0000 show on screen and the issue happens.

This seems to have made a big difference.

```
quit() {

    while read -e -t 0.1; do : ; done
    read  -p "Do you want to quit ? (y/n) " n
    if [ "$n" = 'y' ]; then
        exit
    fi

}
```

I'm struggling to make it happen now.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you have something in stdin that is read into `$n` and since it's different from `y` your script just carries on after executing the trap function. Does that sound possible? If so I suggest checking [this Unix&Linux SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/276531/clear-stdin-before-reading) to discard the content of stdin before prompting for y/n

Comment: Not related to your question, but the `-e` argument to `echo` is best avoided; it's not specified by the POSIX sh standard, and even in bash, its behavior varies wildly depending on the active compile-time and runtime flags. See Stephane's excellent answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo describing the respects in which `echo`'s behavior is unreliable and unportable, *especially* when relying on backslash-escape translation.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `read`'s `-i` flag but given its description I think it's the offender : "If readline is being used to read the line, text is placed into the editing buffer before editing begins." ; it must be placing `0000` into `stdin`, which your `quit()` function reads instead of the `y/n` you'd like

Comment: I think it is the `read -i` - is there anyway around this ? I've followed the link @Aaron provided but i'm not sure how to add that in.. thanks

Comment: @Aaron I don't think it's continuing .. It appears to be hing when this happens.

Comment: Updated question with possible solution..

Comment: I would guess it just seems to hang because it's waiting for another line of input for the main flow's `read`. If you decide to use the solution from the question I linked to, you should empty stdin inside your trap before reading `n`.

Comment: Or `cat /dev/tty | read -r n`, so it does not mess with `stdin` but reads the answer from the terminal device. In this case you will have to determine if the script is running interactive before using such interactive handler.

Comment: Only issue I've found with method I've added to the question, is if you press 'n' then the new line you get doesn't have your previous prefilled answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trap names must not be prefixed with `SIG` as it is undefined.

The other thing you want to do inside your trap handler is:
neutralize the traps
so they don't trigger while handler is processing.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

quit() {
  trap false ABRT INT # Neutralize traps in the quit handler by assigning the false function
  printf '\nDo you want to quit ? (y/N)\n' # Uppercase N show the default choice
  read -r n
  case "${n}" in
    [yY]) # Match y or Y
      exit
    ;;
  esac
  trap quit ABRT INT # Re-enable traps on self
}

trap quit ABRT INT # Attach the SIGABRT and SIGINT traps to the quit function
i=1
while true; do
  echo "$i"
  i=$((i+1))
  sleep 1
done
```

Sample run:

```
1
2
^C
Do you want to quit ? (y/n)
n
3
4
^C
Do you want to quit ? (y/n)
^C5
6
7
8
^C
Do you want to quit ? (y/n)
y
```

Comment: I added a couple more comments

Comment: This suffers the same issue. If you press CTRL+C just at the 'right' the script appears to hang and won't accept any input. The update on my question seems to work better.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
quit() {

  echo "Do you want to quit ? (y/n)"
  read n
  if [ "$n" = 'y' ]; then
    exit
  fi

}

trap quit INT
trap quit SIGINT
trap quit SIGTERM

for i in `seq 1 50`; do
    sleep 1
    echo -e "........"
    site=$(read -p "0000" -e site; echo "$site")
done
```